# Np.where comparation is't working in float column, how to do this?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this dataframe below from a csv file and I want complementary the column "COD_1" with values from "COD_2" if "COD_1" is empty, but `np.where`, don't work.

```
>>> df
        COD_1              COD_2          
0   FX-002-004-736587  FX-002-004-736587  
1   FX-111-000-940898  FX-111-000-940898  
6   FX-002-004-725648                NaN  
7   FX-048-001-171172                NaN  
12                NaN  FX-005-005-080607  
13                NaN  FX-020-001-918590
```

When I compare a unique valeu with "is float(np.nan)" it returns true,

```
>>> df['COD_1'][13] is float(np.nan)
True
>>> df['COD_1'][13] == float(np.nan)
False
```

But when I try compare the entire column with `np.where`, dosen't work:

```
df["COD_1"] = np.where((df['COD_1'] is float(np.nan)), df['COD_2'],df['COD_1'])
```

How can I do that? Why it don't work?

Comment: `df['COD_1'].isna()`

Comment: Thank you @HenryEcker! How does it work? Do you have a link for me to learn more about it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html).

The `is` operator will compare the series `df['COD_1]` to determine if it is `np.nan` and return a single value:

```
print(df['COD_1'] is np.nan)  # False
```

This is, of course, `False` because the Series of values is not `np.nan`

---

`isna`, however, will produce a boolean series based on `nan` values in the column:

```
print(df['COD_1'].isna())
```

```
0     False
1     False
6     False
7     False
12     True
13     True
Name: COD_1, dtype: bool
```

Together with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) it looks like:

```
df['COD_1'] = np.where(df['COD_1'].isna(), df['COD_2'], df['COD_1'])
```

`df`

```
                COD_1              COD_2
0   FX-002-004-736587  FX-002-004-736587
1   FX-111-000-940898  FX-111-000-940898
6   FX-002-004-725648                NaN
7   FX-048-001-171172                NaN
12  FX-005-005-080607  FX-005-005-080607
13  FX-020-001-918590  FX-020-001-918590
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'COD_1': {0: 'FX-002-004-736587', 1: 'FX-111-000-940898',
              6: 'FX-002-004-725648', 7: 'FX-048-001-171172',
              12: np.nan, 13: np.nan},
    'COD_2': {0: 'FX-002-004-736587', 1: 'FX-111-000-940898', 6: np.nan,
              7: np.nan, 12: 'FX-005-005-080607', 13: 'FX-020-001-918590'}
})
```